# Joomla: How to find the source of an html block?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to know where a specific block on a page is coming from.

Is it plugin, the template or something else? Where can I find it in the admin area?

Like in magento you can enable to display block path info and it tells you the template file you need to look at. Other systems place html comments or css names to show extensions and block names.

**Update**

I looked in templates and downloaded the two selected. Then I searched the file for names I found in the html output. It only returned a css file. Now I download the whole page (with out cache) and try again. This is stupid because we are talking about ~8000 files.

Comment: The template perhaps? Kind of hard to tell. Maybe provide a link to your site so the element can be inspected.

Comment: @Lodder I updated my question. Just like to have a strategy how to find the source of a content block. Must be a very common problem.

Comment: It could be coming from the template index.php file, or the template file for the component, the module view, or the module layout. It all depends. As stated before, if you provide a link to your site and specify the area you're looking for, it will be much easier to track where the block is coming from

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for your help. I can't give you a link. Maybe you can describe what you would do given any random page. I updated what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - this is a problem with Joomla installations. With some experience your chances will grow that you find the right files faster. But even after working with Joomla for 6 years now I still sometimes need to to search through all Joomla files (with the texteditor 'find in files'-function) to find something specific.
It gets even worse by the fact that some extensions do produce some output within their controller files.

If you look into the HTML-Code you might find some clues. Modules are surrounded by DIVs with classes like 'module...' in most cases.

Generally these are the places where HTML-Output is produced:
The template-index.html and the template overrides in the /html-subdirectory of your template.
The views in the /views-subdirectories of the components.
The templates-files of the modules in the /tmpl-subdirectories of /modules/modulexyz.
And some Extensions use files from the their /administrator-directory to render the frontend.

Furthermore you should keep in mind, that plugins are able to manipulate anything in the HTML-Output - even HTML-output from other extensions.
I hope that helps a little bit.